# Switch connection before any request Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I tend to switch database connection before any request , any suggestion ?

I use domain route groups :

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'example.com'], function () {


    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
    ... and other routes

});
```

But I want to switch on database connection after  any route group by domain and use one controller to control all domain but with multiple databases.
Any idea how to do that ?
I know that I can switch connection in controller like so :

```
$connection = config('database.connections.mysql');
$conn = DB::connection($connection);
$model = $conn->table('models');
$models = $model->get();
```

for example.
But I want it before any request is made to the app.

Answer (score 0):

I think Laravel middlewares can come in hand here. See documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware

A brief intro to middlewares:

> Middleware provide a convenient mechanism for filtering HTTP requests
>   entering your application. For example, Laravel includes a middleware
>   that verifies the user of your application is authenticated. If the
>   user is not authenticated, the middleware will redirect the user to
>   the login screen. However, if the user is authenticated, the
>   middleware will allow the request to proceed further into the
>   application.
>
> Of course, additional middleware can be written to perform a variety
>   of tasks besides authentication. A CORS middleware might be
>   responsible for adding the proper headers to all responses leaving
>   your application. A logging middleware might log all incoming requests
>   to your application.

You can put all routes that query same database in the same middleware and switch databases accordingly.
Before Middleware will be ideal for this scenario.

Before & After Middleware:

> Whether a middleware runs before or after a request depends on the
>   middleware itself. For example, the following middleware would perform
>   some task before the request is handled by the application.

Comment: you are right ,I knew there could be a way with middlewares but I thought maybe there is a way in routes , so with a bit more code to configure the middleware , changed the view and also database on the fly , thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must have one Middleware which will wrap all the routes inside that group. Inside that Middleware you can switch between database as per your requirements.